# Measure the reachable amount of points by a given distance

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network

I want to measure the amount of points that are reachable given a certain  amount of walking time or walking distance along a streetnetwork. Furthermore, I want to have the amount of points reachable per 'starting' position in a attributetable or other overview.

In other words, I have a streetnetwork (Line features) and I want to calculate per street how many park entry points & sport facility points can be reached (Points) given a certain distance of time limit, and finally have a table that shows per street how many points can be reached.

I believe a solution is a network analysis using ArcGIS. However, I'm not that experienced with the network analysis features

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplistically you can create service areas from each street and then use the output to select by location your points , count them and add them to the streets table. However your street is linear and the distance to your points may vary by your current location on that street. I would do the service areas from the centre of each street, although you could create points along the street then take an average value  but this will produce non discrete values.

Comment: Hi David, this is exactly what I did and it works! Of course I have to take into account that I take the centroid of the street instead of the actual location on the street.